# Is it possible to post a facebook group wall message without facebook API

Tags: c#, facebook, http

I am trying to post facebook messages to a group(my group) wall from my program.

I've seen articles about facebook API but it shares your post with "via AppName"
but my posts shouldn't have that tag(my account is a company account).

I thought about using regular http requests and posts but i can login into facebook but i have no idea how to post to group wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag cannot be removed, it is important to be visible so users can see if the post was done with an App. You are not allowed to automate it without the Graph API btw, so "regular http requests" are out of the question. You are only allowed to post something manually or with the Graph API.

Information on how to post to a group can be found in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed

Keep in mind that you need the `user_groups` permission, and that permission will most likely not get approved:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_groups